# How to location the sub-nav no matter what big of the screen?

Tags: css

http://www.wargameoutfit.com/nav/33.html

When you mouse hover on the navigation font "Two/Three/Four", under the main menu appears the sub-navigation.

Neither I set `#nav li ul { padding-left }` to a fixed value nor I set its value to a percent value. Why the sub-navigation's location is more and more away from the left, when I move down on the screen?

Comment: Would the downgrader please state why they have downgraded this question?

Comment: @Westie Because of [this Meta Stackoverflow question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) although, granted, the OP has made some sort of attempt at posting some images but even then if their domain goes down this question becomes _utterly useless_

Comment: @Bojangles: I see.  In that case, stack2013a, can you show us the code you used to produce the original, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake being made there is that the drop menu has no positioning context other than the browser window. That is, `position: absolute` is set in relation to the browser window, because none of the drop menu's parent elements have position set on them. To change this, add `position: relative` to the top level list items in the menu. Positioned elements are located in relation to the nearest positioned parent element, or in relation to the browser viewport if there are no positioned parents.